# Multiple If Statement Reduction

Tags: java

I'm looking for some help cleaning up the code below and reducing the number of lines. Is there a way to not set anything if the get returns a null?

```
            if (map.get("cpn_rate") != null) {
                collateral.setCoupon(new BigDecimal(map.get("cpn_rate")));
            }
            if (map.get("Price") != null) {
                collateral.setPrice(new BigDecimal(map.get("Price")));
            }
            if (map.get("Par") != null) {
                collateral.setPar(new BigDecimal(map.get("Par")));
            }
            if (map.get("mkt_val") != null) {
                collateral.setMarketValue(new BigDecimal(map.get("mkt_val")));
            }
            if (map.get("Accrued Intr") != null) {
                collateral.setAccurInterest(new BigDecimal(map.get("Accrued Intr")));
            }
            if (map.get("Total Market Value") != null) {
                collateral.setTotMktValue(new BigDecimal(map.get("Total Market Value")));
            }
```

Comment: Is `map` a HashMap collection?

Comment: @YaronGrushka: If it's a `Map`, [that's good enough](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: Side note: be consistent in your code and follow ONE convention when naming variables etc.. `cpn_rate`  is lowercase and has a underscore, `Accrued Intr` is different to that, also `Total Market Value`

Comment: @B001ᛦ:  That doesn't even matter here. Those are *keys*, not variable names.  Those keys could easily be stored in variables that satisfy your code style requirements.

Comment: @Makoto _those are keys, not variable names...._ That is why I said `naming variables etc..`, However it doesn't matter to the machine, but the people who have to work with the code

Comment: Use Optional from Java 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer to the overt question of, "can I make this more concise/terse" is "no".  You're not really going to get what you're looking for in making this more terse or concise, nor would [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) really give you what you're looking for *and* keep your code readable.

The issue is that, when you go to retrieve a key from your map, you're putting it in a different field in your `collateral` instance.  This means that trivial solutions such as looping over the map won't satisfy since you're not going to be able to get the *exact* field you need to map to without getting deep into reflection.

The code you have here, albeit verbose, is perfectly readable and reasonable to any other maintainer to understand what's going on.  I see no incentive to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw in another option since there's more discussion here than I thought there would be.

Sometimes it makes sense to flip logic like this on its head (it may or may not in this case). Instead of having this chunk of code in the mainline code, move it into `Collateral` (or whatever the classname is).

The mainline code would then get cooked down to something like:

```java
collateral.fillFromData(map); // TODO: Name something that makes sense in your domain
```

Or it could be a factory method, or whatever–context would determine the best approach(es).

The `Collateral` class would encapsulate the logic that determines which values are filled, and *how* those values are filled, based on the data passed in. That logic would likely be identical to what's here already (or a brief refactoring to wrap it up as in k5_'s second solution (which I don't have a problem with despite some localized complexity).

This localizes initialization/filling logic to the class that owns that data: this may or may not be reasonable. If it *isn't* reasonable then it's likely there's a missing helper/service/utility class somewhere in here that makes sense in the context of where/how the original code is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If it is no problem to actually set `null` and you just want to avoid the npe creating the BigDecimal. I would go with this helper method.

```
BigDecimal getBigDecimalOrNull(Map<String,String> map, String key){
    String value= map.get(key);
    if (value == null){
       return null;
    }
    return new BigDecimal(value);
}
```

And use it with

```
collateral.setTotMktValue(getBigDecimalOrNull(map, "Total Market Value"));
```

---

If the setting `null` is an actual problem. You can use this helper method

```
void setBigDecimalWhenNotNull(Map<String,String> map, Consumer<BigDecimal> consumer, String key){
    String value= map.get(key);
    if (value == null){
       return null;
    }
    consumer.accept(new BigDecimal(value));
}
```

and use it with:

```
 setBigDecimalWhenNotNull(map, ColleralClass::setToMktValue, "Total Market Value")
```

Comment: That's different behavior, though, which may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes you are correct. Thats why i started the answer with an 'if'. In my experience it is often ok to set `null`, because the value is `null` anyway and you dont change anything. The problem arises with trying to create a `BigDecimal` with `null` as parameter. In my opinion thats one of the few things that makes this actually easier and doesn't rely on lambdas.

Comment: @DaveNewton i added a version with methods references, that doesnt have that behavior. But is harder to read.

Comment: We don't know the context around the respective `setXxx` methods so I'd be hesitant to make any assumptions there (e.g., observers, aspects, side-effects, etc). I know you said "if", I just think it's important to highlight that it's explicitly different, and possibly undesirable, behavior.

Comment: I don't mind the new version (although I'd make the name more descriptive). The *mainline* code would be pretty clear, it's only under some circumstances you'd have to dig into the refactor. IMO keeping the happy path readable and clear is more important.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could use something like

```
Optional.ofNullable(map.get("cpn_rate")).ifPresent(rate => collater.setCoupon(new BigDecimal(rate)));
```

1. Optional.ofNullable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T- will not blow up if map.get("cpn_rate") is null.
2. Optional.ifPresent will only execute the other thing if map.get("cpn_rate") is not null.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(String)` throws a `NullPointerException` if called with `null`

Comment: @k5_ you are correct.  The `new BigDecimal` should be inside the ifPresent method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson Mapper to convert a Map to a POJO, but to be able to do that, you'll need to follow naming convention. The field name in POJO has to match with the key in your Map.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final Collateral collateral = mapper.convertValue(map, Collateral.class);
```

Comment: There's also Commons BeanUtils, but it doesn't seem like that's workable in this case without a lot of string name rework.